# Function of $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for each $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

> Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for each $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}.$

$(a).$ Show that $f(nx) = nf(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $n ∈ \mathbb{Z}.$

$(b).$ Prove that $f(mx) = mf(x)$ for all $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$ and $m ∈ \mathbb{Q}.$

$(c).$ Prove that $f$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

$(d).$ Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $0$, then there is an $m ∈ \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = mx$ for all $x ∈ R$.

$\underline{Attempt}$

When $x=y=0$, we can get $f(0)=0$ and also when $x=-y$, $f(x)=-f(-x)$

$(a).$ For this part I considered  $3$ cases when $n> 0,$ $n<0$ and $n=0$

When $n=0$ it is obviously true.

When $n> 0$, $$f(nx)=f(\underbrace{x+x+x...+x}_{n})=\underbrace{f(x)+f(x)...+f(x)}_{n}=nf(x)$$

When $n<0$, $$f(nx)=f(\underbrace{(-x)+(-x)+(-x)...+(-x)}_{|n|})=\underbrace{f(-x)+f(-x)...+f(-x)}_{|n|}=nf(x)$$

$(b)$. Take $m \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $m=\dfrac{p}{q}$
$$f(mx)=f \left(\dfrac{px}{q} \right)=f\left(p \left(\dfrac{x}{q}\right)\right)=pf\left(\frac{x}{q}\right)$$ using $y=\dfrac{x}{q}$ substitution $f(yq)=f(x)=qf(y)$ hence
$$f(mx)=f \left(\dfrac{px}{q} \right)=\frac{p}{q}f(x)$$

$(c)$.  If $f$ is continuous at $0$,

$\forall \epsilon>0$ $ \exists \delta>0$  such that $|x-0|<\delta$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ imply $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f(x)|< \dfrac{\epsilon}{(1+|p|)}$

let consider  $a$ and $p$ $\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a=px$, from part $(a)$ and $(b)$

$$|f(x)-f(a)| \leq |f(x)|+|f(a)|=|f(x)|(1+|p|)<\epsilon \text{ whenever }  |x-a|<\delta_1$$

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ it also continuous at $0$, So we can conclude
$f$ is continuous at $0$ if and only if $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

$(d).$ Define a function $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$ for each $x, y ∈ \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=mx$

given that $f$ is continuous at $0$ so from part $(c)$ $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $m=f(1)$

This is what I tried. If there Is anything wrong correct me and not sure part $(c)$ and $(d)$

Comment: In part D , how do you know that $m$ is rational?

Comment: @Infinity_hunter define a function with $m$ is not rational is that correct?

Comment: In part (b) $m$ is only rational number not any real number

Comment: @Infinity_hunter yes isn't it correct part $b$ and $d$?

Comment: For part (c) use $f(x) - f(a ) = f(x-a)$ and substitute $y = x- a$ and observe that $f(y)$ is continous at 0

Comment: oh got it my proof is not valid for irrational numbers

Answer (score 1):

To prove part (d) we use sequential criterion of continuity.

Observe that for any rational $x$ there exist $m$ such that $f(x) = mx$.

Consider a sequence $x_n$ which converges to an irrational $x$ and by hypothesis we have $f$ is continous at all real numbers. Consider a subseqence $(p_n)$ of $x_n$ such that it contains all rational terms. Then we have $f(p_n ) = mp_n \to mx = f(x)$. Now if no subseqence with irrational terms exists then we are done else let $q_n$ be subseqence with irrational terms. Given that $f$ is continous at $x$ we must have $f(q_n) \to f(x)$ and by uniqueness of limits we have $f(x) = mx$

Answer (score 1):

This is from the book ' Introduction to Real Analysis ' by S.K. Mapa(7 th edition).
This is a worked out example at the end of chapter 8, Continuity. This is the answer to your question,  only the converse part of (c) is not given . But you can  prove it similarly.  If you still have doubt,  then comment below. [image]

Answer (score 1):

$ a) $ : First of all $ f\left(0\right)=0 $. And for any $ x\in\mathbb{R} $, $ 0=f\left(x-x\right)=f\left(x\right)+f\left(-x\right)\iff f\left(-x\right)=-f\left(x\right)$.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Let $ x\in\mathbb{R} $ and $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, we have :
\begin{aligned} f\left(nx\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(f\left(\left(k+1\right)x\right)-f\left(kx\right)\right)}&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(f\left(\left(k+1\right)x\right)+f\left(-kx\right)\right)}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{f\left(\left(k+1\right)x-kx\right)}\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{f\left(x\right)}\\&=nf\left(x\right) \end{aligned}

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $If $ n\in\mathbb{Z}_{-}=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\mathbb{N}^{*} $, then : $$ f\left(nx\right)=-f\left(\left(-n\right)x\right)=-\left(-n\right)f\left(x\right)=nf\left(x\right) $$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Thus $ \left(\forall \left(n,x\right)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}\right),\ f\left(nx\right)=nf\left(x\right) $.

$ b) $ : Let $ p\in\mathbb{Z} $, and $ q\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $. $ m=\frac{p}{q} $. We have : $$ pf\left(x\right) = f\left(q\times\frac{p}{q}x\right)=q f\left(\frac{p}{q}x\right)\iff f\left(mx\right)=mf\left(x\right)$$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Thus $ \left(\forall m\in\mathbb{Q}\right),\ f\left(mx\right)=m f\left(x\right) $.

$ c) $: $ \Longleftarrow )$ If $ f $ is continuous on $ \mathbb{R} $ then it is continuous at $ 0 $.

$\ \ \ \ \Longrightarrow )$ Suppose $ f $ is continuous at $ 0 $. Let $ a\in\mathbb{R} $ :

$$ \lim_{x\to a}{f\left(x\right)}=\lim_{x\to 0}{f\left(x+a\right)}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(f\left(x\right)+f\left(a\right)\right)}=f\left(0\right)+f\left(a\right)=f\left(a\right) $$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Since $ a $ is an arbitrary real. then $ f $ is continuous on $ \mathbb{R} $.

$ d): $ Suppose $ f $ is continuous at $ 0 $.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ Let $ x\in\mathbb{R} $, and $ \left(x_{n}\right)_{n}\in\mathbb{Q}^{\mathbb{N}} $ such that $ x_{n}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}x $.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $We have for all $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ : $$ f\left(x_{n}\right)=x_{n}f\left(1\right) $$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $Since $ f $ is continuous, we have $ \lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}{f\left(x_{n}\right)}=f\left(x\right) $. That means if we took $ n $ to $ +\infty $ in the previous equality, we obtain : $$ f\left(x\right)=x f\left(1\right) $$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $ f\left(1\right) $ is a constant, it can be anything, let's denote it $ m $. We've just proven that, for any $ x\in\mathbb{R} $, we have : $$ f\left(x\right)=mx $$